# how to display an item once from a list where that item shows up multiple times in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I've written the code in my .html.erb file but am thinking it might more sense to write it in my controller? This code returns all the names. I'm trying to figure out how to fetch a tag name only once and if a user inputs a tag name that has already been used it does not show up again.

```
<ul>
  <% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
    <% pic.tags.each do |tag| %>
      <li>
        <%= tag.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do you get the @pictures value ? from db ?

Comment: Right now I receive every item that is inputed

Comment: Can you post that code ?

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, @pictures is an instance variable in one of my controllers. It's quite a bit of code.

Comment: try this pic.tags.uniq_by(&:name),each do //then show only unique name here

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
<ul>
  <% @pictures.flat_map { |pic| pic.tags.map(&:name) }.uniq.each do |name| %>
  <li>
    <%= name %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/9vq3aP)

Comment: The item still prints

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <% @pictures.collect{|x| x.tags.uniq}.flatten.uniq.each do |tag| %>
      <li>
        <%= tag.name %>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
      <% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
    <% pic.tags.uniq_by(&:name).each do |tag| %>
      <li>
        <%= tag.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array#-` method for all items collected that the user enters.

Answer (score 0):

this is relative to how you store the tag values, inside your save method you should make the tags array to be uniq.